# What is this error and how do I fix it: Finder got an error: Can’t make class file

Tags: macos, file, applescript, automator, finder

I've just started out with AppleScript and I am trying to make a "new text file" thing in Automator. I keep getting this error: "Finder got an error: Can’t make class file."

Here is my code:

````
tell application "Finder"
    set filename to display dialog "Enter Filename" default answer "newfile"
    make new file at (target of front window) with properties {name:text returned of filename, file type:text}
end tell```
````

Answer (score 0):

A `get` statement is usually optional, but in this case it is needed in order to evaluate the location specifier, since the statement is in the middle of the `make` command - see the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW56).  For example:

```
   make new file at (get target of front window) …
```

You can also evaluate the location specifier using a separate statement:

```
   set destination to target of front window
   make new file at destination …
```